# Can't update BIOS via FreeDOS on Aspire One D255: fatal error (1307) not enough memory

Tags: memory, bios, freedos, acer-aspire-one

This is pretty much a copy of [the post I made on the Acer Community forums](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/566374/cannot-update-aod255-bios-via-freedos-in-order-to-get-2gb-ram-stick-working#latest), also posting here to hopefully get help faster.

---

I've been trying to install a 2GB RAM stick in my Aspire One D255, however once it's in there it won't boot to BIOS, just a blank screen and fans stop spinning. I've looked around and I think a good step is to update the BIOS to v3.16 (after putting the factory 1GB RAM back in, of course).

I've already wiped Windows off my C drive trying (and failing) to install Kubuntu. So I installed FreeDOS on there and (on another PC) copied the BIOS update files onto a USB drive and then moved them to the root of C on my laptop. The file structure is as follows:

```
C:\>dir
 Volume in drive C is FREEDOS2016
 Volume Serial Number is 113E-16F7

 Directory of C:\

FDOS                 <DIR> 04-27-2019  3:20p
AUTOEXEC BAT         1,319 04-27-2019  3:21p
COMMAND  COM        66,945 08-28-2006 10:38p
FDCONFIG SYS           762 04-27-2019  3:21p
FLASH    EXE        16,714 04-27-2019  3:42p
FLASHIT  EXE       489,486 01-10-2009 10:02p
KERNEL   SYS        46,685 05-11-2016  9:42p
PAV70D2  FD      2,097,152 04-22-2011 10:48p
PAV70D3  FD      2,097,152 04-22-2011 10:00p
         8 file(s)      4,816,215 bytes
         1 dir(s)   2,136,309,760 bytes free
```

`Flash.exe`, `FlashIt.exe` & the 2 `.fd` files are the update files. The rest is part of FreeDOS.

But when I run `Flash.exe`, I get this error:

```
C:\>FLASH.EXE
C:\>Flashit PAV70D3.fd /all
DOS/4GW Professional fatal error (1307): not enough memory
one file removed.
```

`mem` returns this:

```
C:\>mem

Memory Type        Total       Used       Free
----------------  --------   --------   --------
Conventional          639K        18K       621K
Upper                  68K        19K        49K
Reserved              317K       317K         0K
Extended (XMS)   1,036,776K     1,316K 1,035,460K
----------------  --------   --------   --------
Total memory     1,037,800K     1,670K 1,036,130K

Total under 1 MB      707K        37K       670K

Total Expanded (EMS)                8,640K (8,847,360 bytes)
Free Expanded (EMS)                 8,192K (8,388,608 bytes)

Largest executable program size       621K (635,904 bytes)
Largest free upper memory block        48K ( 49,520 bytes)
FreeDOS is resident in the high memory area.
```

Before you say "don't bother, just buy a new laptop", I recently received this D255 as a gift.

Please help, as I have 30 days to return the 2GB RAM stick if the problem is with the stick itself (however I highly doubt that, since I bought another 2GB RAM ram stick before this one but that didn't work either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting FreeDOS in Safe Mode made `Flash.exe` work! My BIOS is now updated to v3.16. Let's hope this makes my PC work with 2GB RAM...